# Recovering encryptfs volume from old Ubuntu install

Tags: 10.04, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I have some backups of an encryptfs systems. I am fairly sure they have no useful data but I want to experiment how I would have recovered it.

I do not have the long recovery key, because, who really have those when they need it?

I do have some very good guesses what my login password was at the time, but i can't really find a good guide for this case.

First question is on the terminology. From the documentation I am unsure what maps to login password, recovery key, Private.sig, wrapped passphrase, unwrapped passphrase...

Second question is what were the defaults circa Ubuntu 10.04 for these questions bellow? I ask because my current process is:

1. mount -t ecryptfs .Private /testing
2. ls /testing
3. see wrong files
4. umount /testing
5. repeat with another password guess

Which might be failing because of the wrong values here, not necessarily because i typed in the wrong login password.

```
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24
 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16
Selection [aes]: 
Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 2) 32
 3) 24
Selection [16]: 
Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: 
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: 
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=...
WARNING: Based on the contents of [/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt],
it looks like you have never mounted with this key 
before. This could mean that you have typed your 
passphrase wrong.

Would you like to proceed with the mount (yes/no)? : yes
Would you like to append sig [...] to
[/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt] 
in order to avoid this warning in the future (yes/no)? : no
Not adding sig to user sig cache file; continuing with mount.
Mounted eCryptfs
```